# closing a database handle

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a generic function that closes connections and it takes a dbh, the currently open database handle by ref.

I call it like this

closeconnection($dbh)

depending on the case whether this dbh was a sqlsrv dbh or a mysql dbh, I do one of the two things;

`sqlsrv_close( $dbh);`

or

`mysql_close($dbh);`

Short of passing the connection type in the function call, is there a way to find out whether this is a mysql or mssql handle programmatically by simply probing the $dbh which was passed by ref?

Comment: Short is putting it at application-wide scope.

Comment: Why not use PDO?  There are both mysql and sqlsrv drivers for PDO, using PDO for both DB types will give you a unified interface to the DBMS and you can close the connection by simply unsetting the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`get_resource_type($dbh);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php).  It'll return `mysql link` for a MySQL DB handle.  I don't know what it will return for anything else as MySQL is all I have handy.

Comment: Thanks Crontab, it returns "SQL Server Connection".

Answer (score 2):

A way using an application-wide could be defining an interface.

```
// connection interface
interface db
{
  public function close($conn);
}
```

Providing implementations for the used drivers.

```
// mysql
class mysql implements db
{
  public function close($conn) { 
    mysql_close($conn);
  }
}
// mssql
class mssql implements db {
  public function close($conn) {
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
  }
}
```

Using an application-wide variable to instantiate the proper driver.

```
if($driver == "mysql") {
  $db = new mysql();
} elseif($driver == "mssql") {
  $db = new mssql();
}
...
$db::close($conn);
```

This is like the most common way to handle it.

Also as anyone will recommend you, you should use start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to tackle this.

Comment: thank you Alexander but the whole point of the question was how to get the $driver being mysql or not...  crontab addressed it. thank you for your time. I'm new to PHP. What's a good resource you can recommend about the interface and learning when and when not to use it?

Comment: You already know what `$driver` is, you are simply choosing to forget it ;). Simply read about OOP to learn about interface and related.